# Getting a max value and the corresponding columns in a performant way in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have an odd situation.

Suppose I need to know the following information: For a given Bakery, I need to know *all* the information about their sweetest cake, and *all* the information about their latest cake. So our data looks something like this.

```
-------------------------------------
bakery | name      | created_timestamp |  sweetness_score
marios | blueberry | 100               | 4
marios | razberry  | 115               | 2
luigis | angels    | 120               | 5
luigis | devils    | 155               | 1
-------------------------------------
```

The final data output should look like

```
{
  mario:
    sweetestCake:{
        name: blueberry,
        sweetness_score: 4,
        created_timestamp: 100
    },
    mostRecentCake: {
        name: razberry,
        sweetness_score: 2,
        created_timestamp: 115
    }
  },
  luigi: // same concept but for luigi's cakes
```

I am using a RANK window function and selecting only where RANK = 1. For example, the sweetest cake can be found with

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY (BAKERY) ORDER BY sweetness_score DESC)
    AS rank_of_sweetness
) as sweetness 
WHERE rank_of_sweetness = 1;
```

but this is not very performant.

I have fiddled with a *lot* off different ideas using `MAX` and the window function `LAST_VALUE`, which retrieve the correct `sweetness_score`, but getting the other columns I need has been a pain.

How can I do this in a more efficient way? or is RANK going to be my best bet no matter what?

Answer (score -1):

The `rank()` solution is fine, and is one of the canonical approaches to the problem:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        rank() over(partition by bakery order by sweetness_score desc) rn1,
        rank() over(partition by bakery order by created_timestamp desc) rn2
     from mytable t
)
where 1 in (rn1, rn2)
```

In Postgres, you can also use `distinct on()`. That's a handy extension, that might be more optimized. Getting both results at once could be done with `union` (on purpose instead of `union all`, in case a single row has both the greatest sweetness and latest timestamp):

```
(
    select distinct on(bakery) *
    from mytable
    order by bakery, sweetness_score desc
) union (
    select distinct on(bakery) *
    from mytable
    order by bakery, created_timestamp desc
)
```

I would be curious to see if the new `fetch` clause, available in Postgres 13, would be helpful here. One upside is that you can use it to filter on both matches at once (which `distinct on` can't do):

```
select *
from mytable 
order by least(
    rank() over(partition by bakery order by sweetness_score desc),
    rank() over(partition by bakery order by created_timestamp desc)
)
fetch first row with ties
```

If none of that helps, then an alternative approach is to fall back on the correlated subquery solution:

```
select *
from mytable t
where 
    t.sweetness_score = (
        select max(t1.sweetness_score)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.bakery = t.bakery
    )
    or t.created_timestamp = (
        select max(t1.created_timestamp)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.bakery = t.bakery
    )
```

For this query, you want indexes on `(bakery, sweetness_score)` and `(bakery, created_timestamp)`.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, I think its fine. They should really require you to have a better answer before allowing you to downvote lol.

distinct on with union doesnt _seeem_ like it would be performant to me, but it might be worth a shot!